# How to make a process restart over and over again when checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, process, restart

I want to create an auto restarter for my server. I have added a checkbox and made all required checks but I don't have any idea how to make that process restart upon crash.

Here is my code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string world = textBox1.Text;
    string auth = textBox2.Text;

    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0 || textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check if you selected the path for worldserver and authserver");
        }
        else
        {
            //here i need something to restart those 2 processes after crash/close
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Fix the crash part, then you don't need this.

Comment: is hard to do that related to what i want it for , btw i told you in my thread when checkbox is checked when you close that program it will restart again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to start a process is to use the `Start` static method of the `Process` class:

```
Process.Start("yourapp.exe");
```

For access to more specific options, you can set up a `ProcessStartInfo` object instead:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "yourapp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "-arg1 val1";

var exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
exeProcess.Start();
```

To check whether the process in question is still running, you can use this:

```
var matchingProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourapp");
var isRunning = matchingProcesses.Length > 0;
```

And you can put that in a method and poll every few seconds or milliseconds (depending on how fast you want to respond):

```
var aTimer = new Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(YourMethod);
aTimer.Interval = 1000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

These classes are found in the `System.Diagnostics` and `System.Timers` namespaces, respectively.

Comment: not working ... i can't find anny ways to do that :| , when checkbox is checked , even if you close that program it will start again , when checkbox is unchecked , program won't start and i'm talking about a different program than my application

Comment: The ways to do that are described in my answer. The checkbox state checking is up to you (and you already seem to have an event handler, so that part is solved). If the checkbox state is "checked", start a timer (in my answer) to periodically and asyncrhonously invoke a method that: checks whether the external program is running (also in my answer) and, if it's not running, launches it (also in my answer). If the checkbox state is "unchecked", then disable that same timer. If you're having difficulties applying what I've described, please provide details on how you tried it and how it failed.

Comment: nvm ive been looking again on your codes and i got it how to make it work using tick timesr :D thx btw

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not C# (but better, it works with almost any program), you can do an auto restarter in batch (or in bash, but I won't put the code here), and it will be enough for most cases:

```
@echo off
:start
myprogram.exe %*
if exist myprogam.lock goto start
```

inside your program:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(checkBox1.Checked)
  {
     using (System.IO.File.Create("myprogam.lock"));
  }
  else
  {
     System.IO.File.Delete("myprogam.lock")
  }
}
```

you should also create the file in your main or init code.

bonus: you can delete the file if your program exits cleanly (or on some errors), and it won't restart.

to use, just put the first code in a .bat file you put in your program folder, and use this to start the program.